# Simplest way to check the users in channel with discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a simple bot, all I want it to do is wait for me to type a command with an argument (a vc), so for example when I type `!channel general`,  the bot will return a list of the members in that channel. So if Bob and Jeff are in General the bot will return `member_list = ['Bob', 'Jeff']` Any easy way to do that?

Update:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def members(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    member_list = [i.name for i in channel.members]
    print(member_list)
    await ctx.send(member_list) # or return member_list whatever you want

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Here's my code up above, when I run bot it does not do anything when I type `$members general`, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `VoiceChannel.members`

```py
@bot.command()
async def members(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    member_list = [i.name for i in channel.members]
    await ctx.send(member_list) # or return member_list whatever you want
```